# Delphi Tokyo, drc file

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

There is an extra character `'L'` in each line of DRC file generated by Delphi Tokyo.

e.g.

```
System_SysConst_SArgumentMissing,   L"No argument for format '%s'"
```

Build using Delphi XE, no extra 'L'

e.g.

```
SysConst_SArgumentMissing,  "No argument for format '%s'"
```

Does anyone know the meaning of `'L'` and how to avoid it?
Thanks

Comment: A preceeding `L` is how C/C++ and resource scripts specify a char/string literal is Unicode instead of Ansi. It doesn't apply to Delphi at all. Don't worry about it, this is normal.

Comment: What problem is the presence of that *L* causing you specifically?

Comment: My project has two versions, Delphi XE and Delphi Tokyo

Comment: I need drc file for customizing UI label captions. I have to use ($IF CompilerVersion=32) to deal with that

Comment: @HongSong deal with WHAT exactly? What is the EXACT problem you are having? XE uses Unicode, same as Tokyo. Delphi has been using Unicode since 2009.

Comment: I read text from DRC file generated by Tokyo, I have to remove 'L'